Azure FrontDoor "Redirect all traffic to use HTTPS" not working
In an Azure FrontDoor route, I have selected "Redirect all traffic to use HTTPS"

However, when navigating to my site http://example.com in a browser for the first time, it does not redirect to https://example.com but instead shows an Azure FrontDoor "Page not found" error page. How can I get FrontDoor to redirect HTTP to HTTPS?

For the redirect from http://example.com to work, you need to enable the HTTP protocol. FrontDoor will then be able to serve a redirect response when users visit http://example.com.

